# search function - goes to "index of/" old sub domain

Tags: wordpress, search

I had a wordpress website which we were developing on a subdomain website.org.nz/new

when we wanted the website to go live and available for everyone we moved it to website.org.nz/

The search function is not working properly after we moved it to the main domain. 
Example if I type "register" in the search box and hit search button, i get taken to an empty page with the following text
"Index of /new
Parent Directory
"
here is an example of the link.
https://website.org.nz/new/?s=register

if I delete the "/new" from the link, it works well.
https://website.org.nz/?s=register

where can I possibly go to fix this issue?, FYI I am using The7 theme if that matters. the whole website is running fine, no errors.